# Toggling subequations

Tags: spacing, environments

For a current project, I employed the `subequations` environment.

There are loads of equations, albeit tiny ones, in the document, and in certain sections/chapters, they amass to three-digit piles (meaning e.g. Eq. 2.102). So, with the help of subequations, grouping related equations, that problem is nicely handled. I consider it needed and nice... my supervisor does not.

Now I'm stuck with a document full of `subequation`-environments of which I have to get rid.

Surprisingly,

```
\renewenvironment{subequations}{}{}
```

did the job without any complaints. But knowing LateX, that surely can't be the proper way to do it?

I noticed, toggling that line of code, that content gets shuffled around. So spaces are altered, probably for the worse!

What is a safe, better workaround?

Comment: If spaces were altered, this must depend on your usage. Perhaps try `\renewenvironment{subequations}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespacesafterend}`.

Comment: That seems to have done it. At least I cant notice anything changing anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
\renewenvironment{subequations}
  {\ignorespaces}%         \begin{subequations}
  {\ignorespaces‌​afterend}% \end{subequations}
```

which should gobble all spaces that may have been inserted by its position in your code.